# Application crashes when searching ONE word

Tags: objective-c, exception, xcode4, uisearchbar

I'm making my UISearchBar working and i've noticed that if i type a word, just ONE, contained in more controllers (for example "a") and i select a row, i get an unexpected crash. If i search for more than a word it works, even if contained in more than 1 controller.

i'm getting a NSRangeException:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'
```

at line

```
cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

of my code (i have 3 sections)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{      
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   //Get the nib

    NSString *cellValue = nil;

    if(searching)
        cellValue = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else {

        NSDictionary *dictionary =[listaOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Elementi"];
        cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    NSDictionary *dict = [listaOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Elementi"];
    cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ; //here's the error


    if (indexPath.section == 0) 
    {    
        if ([cellValue isEqual: @"FirstNib"]){

            FIrstViewController *firstController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil]; 
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:appsController animated:YES]; 
            [firstController release];

        if ([cellValue isEqual: @"SecondNib"]){

            secondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil]; 
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES]; 
            [secondController release];
        }

//and so on

    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1){

        if ([cellValue isEqual: @"ThirdNib"]){  
            ThirdViewController *firstController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil]; 
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:ThirdController animated:YES]; 
            [ThirdController release];
        }
        //and so on
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {

        if ([cellValue isEqual @"FourthNib"]){  
        FourthViewController *firstController = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil]; 
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:FourthController animated:YES]; 
            [FourthController release];
        }


}
```

(the line is not the one in the IF state)

Now. I know that it goes over the array, trying to access to the 10th element. 
Passing the mouse over the line "array" here

```
cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
```

It tells me there are 9 objects on it, while there should be 45, as i declared them here, for the key @"Elementi":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    listaOggetti = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *arrayDesk = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"First",@"Second",@"Third"..@"9th", nil];
    NSArray *sortedDesk = [arrayDesk sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSDictionary *dictDesk = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sortedDesk forKey:@"Elementi"];

    NSArray *arrayLion = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First1",@"Second1" ... @"30th", nil];
    NSArray *sortedLion = [arrayLion sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSDictionary *dictLion = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sortedLion forKey:@"Elementi"];


    NSArray *arrayRestore = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First2",@"Second2" ... @"6th", nil];
    NSArray *sortedRestore = [arrayRestore sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSDictionary *dictRest = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:sortedRestore forKey:@"Elementi"];


    [listaOggetti addObject:dictDesk];
    [listaOggetti addObject:dictLion];
    [listaOggetti addObject:dictRest];

    copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TIPS", @"Tips");
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"window.png"]];

    //Add the search bar
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    searching = NO;
    letUserSelectRow = YES;

    CGRect bounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + searchBar.bounds.size.height;
    self.tableView.bounds = bounds;

}
```

Shouldn't it see all the object for the key `@"Elementi"`? I'm on it from days, i can't understand how to solve, though.

Any help appreciated

**EDIT **

I noticed that

```
NSDictionary *dict = [listaOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

has only 9 elements, as well as in the first array, but i have 3 dictionaries: dictDesk, dictLion, dictRest.

How can i do to select all the 45 elements in the NSDictionary?

**EDIT 2 **
Thanks to pengOne, i finally filled a global array with my 45 elements,this way

```
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:[[listaOggetti objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Elementi"]];
    [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:[[listaOggetti objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"Elementi"]];
    [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:[[listaOggetti objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"Elementi"]];
```

Now all i need to do it's to adapt something like this

```
NSDictionary *dictionary =[listaOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Elementi"];
cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to the global array i've done, so it can let me search and select contents, either from tableView and SearchView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
        NSString* cellValue=@"";
        if (searching)
            cellValue = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        else{
             NSDictionary *dictionary = [listaOggetti objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
             NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Elementi"];
             cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       }
       if ([cellValue isEqual: @"Apps on specific Desks"] || [cellValue isEqual: @"Applicazioni su più Scrivanie"]){

        AppsViewController *appsController = [[AppsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AppsViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:appsController animated:YES]; 
        [appsController release];
    }

}
```

Comment: THAT'S IT! thank you very much. You saved my life after 3 days stuck! ;D

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that you are sending this message:

```
[array objectAtIndex:9];
```

when `array` has 9 object, and it only responds to

```
[array objectAtIndex:0];
...
[array objectAtIndex:8];
```

The lines you need to investigate are:

```
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Elementi"];
    selectedRow = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Check `[dictionary objectForKey:@"Elementi"]`. It appears to be an `NSArray` with 9 objects, when it needs to be an `NSArray` with at least 10 objects in order to access the object at index 10.

---

For your `viewDidLoad` method, it looks to me like `listaOggetti` is an `NSMutableArray` with 3 objects: `dictDesk` has 9 elements, `dictLion` has 30 elements, and `dictRest` has 6 elements.

To fix this error, you will need to change the number of rows in section 0 to be 9, the number of rows in section 1 to be 30 and the number of rows in section 2 to be 6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read around that was a problem with numbersOfRowsInSections, i've updated the code. By the way, the dictionary has elements coming from 3 different arrays. I still don't get the problem though, it crashes only when i type a word contained in more controllers name. What should i change?

Comment: @Phillip: See above for the solution to your problem, and please remove your duplicate posting. Thanks.

Comment: @Phillip: copyListOfItems has no items. Just log the size of each array and you should be able to solve this easily. This isn't some grand mystery. You know exactly what and where the error is.

Comment: Updated, i'm almost done with that: all i need to do it's to adapt the structure to the array i've created.